# IE 8 (Win XP) does not download files from the mvc web-application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8, download

Faced with the following problem. IE 8 (Win XP) does not download files from MVC web-application (the application is deployed on an intranet) gives an error:

**"can not load [filename] from [server].
Unable to open the knot of the Internet. Host is not available or can not be found. Please try again later."**

Later noticed and to external sites is the same error when I try to download anything from the Internet. All rescues restart your computer after it is loaded and everything works. But over time, the error is repeated again and again restart saves. Occurs only on Windows XP, Win at 7 and 8 such problems were not observed.

This problem is only with IE on XP. Google Chrome Portable on the same computer will ship the files. Your settings are lost, everything is clean ... What I just did))) With all the normal proxy identity. Already played with access to the user folder (https://superuser.com/questions/131262/ie8-unable-to-download-files). The fact is that when you restart the computer all the files are loaded fine, but over time this issue comes out.

Does anyone have any ideas about this??

Thank you.